# How do I develop for iOS devices compatability-wise (not an actual mobile app)?

Tags: ios, meteor

While I do own an iPad, developing for it requires me to deploy my app and then visiting it on the device, since I can't access the localhost. There has to be a better way, but googling it has turned up nothing, only links to how to turn your web app into a phone app.

There has to be a better way, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to get your computer's IP address. If it's a Mac you can open up **System Preferences** and head to **Network**

[image]

Select the WiFi network that is shared with your iPhone/iPad, or network adapter that is connected to a Wifi Hotspot which the iPhone is connected to.

Connect using the IP address instead of localhost.

I.e if you use

```
http://localhost:3000
```

You would use the IP address of your machine, i.e as on the screenshot:

```
http://192.168.8.102:3000
```

On your ipad. The iPad will use your WiFi network to connect to your machine at this point.